# Exporting text and creating buttons from XML using JQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, import

I'm importing multiple text from an xml sheet and creating clickable buttons on the fly using Jquery into an existing html page and div.

The text and clickable buttons seem to import okay, the buttons react to the mouse rollover, clickability, etc - all functionality seems there - but the script in my .click function in the .html page does not work.

As a troubleshoot, I copied the html and paste directly from a live page (after importing from xml using the same method) into the same html page, and the button works perfectly - as you would expect.
Is there something weird about the way this does or doesn't work with an xml import?

Here is the full JQuery import from xml sheet block of code:

```
$(function(){    
        $('#hideText').click(function() {  
        $("#readingText").fadeOut(100);
        $("#viewText").fadeIn();
        $("#hideText").fadeOut();
        var qnum = 1;           

        $("#questions").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
            url: "mc1.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                var quiz = "quiz"+qnum ++;
                $(xml).find(quiz).each(function(){
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var questionNo = $(this).find('questionNo').text();
                var q1 = $(this).find('q1').text();
                var A = $(this).find('A').text();

                $('<div class="items" id="link_'+id+'"> 
 </div>').html( '<p style="color:green">'+questionNo+  '</p>' + '<p style="color:red">'
 +q1+ '</p>' + '</p>').appendTo('#questions');
$(this).find('choice').each(function(){
var A = $(this).find('A').text();
var B = $(this).find('B').text();
var C = $(this).find('C').text();
var D = $(this).find('D').text();
var E = $(this).find('E').text();
 $('<div id = "AA" class="1" ></div>').html('<p class="tab2"> <a href="#" 
     class="q_but">A</a> '+A+' <br><br> ').appendTo('#link_'+id);
 $('<div id = "BB" class="2"></div>').html('<p class="tab2"> <a href="#"    
 class="q_but">B</a> '+B+' <br><br>').appendTo('#link_'+id);
 $('<div id = "CC" class="3"></div>').html('<p class="tab2"> <a href="#" 
 class="q_but">C</a> '+C+' <br><br>').appendTo('#link_'+id);
 $('<div id = "DD" class="4"></div>').html('<p class="tab2"> <a href="#" 
 class="q_but">D</a> '+D+' <br><br>').appendTo('#link_'+id);
 $('<div id = "EE" class="5"></div>').html('<p class="tab2"> <a href="#" 
 class="q_but">E</a> '+E+' <br><br>').appendTo('#link_'+id);
$("#questions").fadeIn(2000);           

                    });
                });
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Here is a test click function to test that the imported buttons ware working

```
$(function(){    
        $('#AA').click(function() {  
        $("#questions").fadeOut();
        });
    })
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: `$('<div id = "AA" class="A" ></div>')` - this first part doesn't make a lot of sense, as the `$("")` is a selector, so you can use `$("#AA")` to grab a `div` with jQuery.
As Oscar Jara said below, you'll need to use the `.on` method for capturing the click events of elements added after the `document` fires its `ready` event.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this being a selector and "doesn't make a lot of sense" What syntax do you think I should be using instead?
The .on method didn't make any difference, but it's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes when the data is loaded in the DOM and you are not able to access 'AA' using simple click.

Try this, `on()` is the equivalent of deprecated `live()`

```
$(function(){    
   $('#AA').on('click', function(){  
      $("#questions").fadeOut();
   });
});
```

Comment: That didn't make any difference, unfortunately. But I discovered something strange, which might shed light on it.
Using Dreamweaver, I previewed the page (F12) and tested it as usual.
The buttons don't work. However, if I save that preview web page to my hard drive, then open it up from that saved position, the buttons work perfectly.
How comes, do you think?

Comment: I made an edit to this, @user1404304, but it's not showing until peer reviewed. It may solve your problem.

Comment: @ahren: Whilst I agree with [your edit](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/270177), it's too much of a "Radical Change": You're putting words in the authors mouth. The best approach would be either add the fixes as a comment here, or add your own answer and fix the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my edit didn't get approved! haha.
So the way `.on()` works, is that you attach the event handler to the parent element, and it waits for the event to bubble up from the element that was clicked. `.live()` was it's predecessor, and worked by attaching the events to the `body` element - which meant an awful lot of bubbling before the event actually got handled.

Basically, we're doing the same thing, except we're adding an extra parameter, which is the class name (or any CSS selector) of the element that's going to be added later!

```
$(function(){    
   $('#link_1').on('click', '.q_but', function(){ 
      $("#questions").fadeOut();
   });
});
```

Adding it to the `#AA` didn't work because that too was added after the `document ready` event - so for now I put in `#link_1` - you'll need to change this for each ID - although, this would work better (and your code would be neater) if all of the `#link_x` elements had a class!

(fingers crossed it works this time!)

=)

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work either. Button still not working.

Comment: Thanks - but still not working! This is so frustrating - such an apparent trivial issue. Am I allowed to send you the entire script (import from xml code) on this forum?

Comment: You can edit your question above to include your entire script if you like... Although, generally I find if it's too long, people won't try and debug it (because it shows no effort in debugging yourself to narrow down the problem) - but go for it, I'll have a wee look.
Alternatively, you could set up a jsfiddle? That way others could get it working without having the back and forth trial and error.

Comment: Thanks for taking a "wee" look at this - I've just updated the original edit.

Comment: Yes, I saw your edit - but it doesn't work either. I agree that the thing is probably not working because it was added after the document ready event - this is confirmed by it working full after I saved the loaded file separately or after I copy and paste the imported text from the loaded preview file after into the original source file (see my comment above).
 But what do you mean about adding a class and improving the code neatness? All the buttons have a class "q-but" which is in the css sheet.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: ah, what i mean is this snippet: `on('click', '.q_but', function` used to be `on('click', 'q_but', function` - notice the period (.) infront of `q_but`

Comment: Also, what I meant from the neatness by adding a class, is that if all the `#link_1` `#link_2` etc had a class, then you could assign one `.on()` handler to handle them all, instead of having to write multiple, or add multiple selectors in your jQuery.

Comment: Yes, I saw the addition of the  period and tried that, but not working still.
How would I set up a class for the buttons different from what it is now? Are you saying they all should be the same class  that they should all be #link_1, for example?